# cannot install tensor flow cudart64_91 not found

Tags: windows, tensorflow

I  installed tensorflow-gpu on windows.My PC have cuda toolkit version v9.1 and cudann version v7 and latest nvdia drivers 390.77.I tried the validation code .But it gives me an error as follows

> import tensorflow as tf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
>       ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in 
>       self_check.preload_check()
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
>       % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
>   ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
>   (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSsnR5jd0s64LZPCQ7RuM8pSsvM78X82/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow 1.5 is built against CUDA 9.0. The error also tells you in the end:

> Download and install **CUDA 9.0**

You need CUDA version 9.0, **not** 9.1